# Stored Procedure - trying to get Field Sizes

Tags: mysql, procedure

I imported a huge database from another SQL application and converted it to MySQL. In order to speed up the process I created the text fields with an arbitrary length.

I want to modify each table and make the fields no bigger than they need to be. Based on this site I came up with these two procedures

```
    DROP PROCEDURE getFieldMaxWidth;
DROP PROCEDURE modifyFieldMaxWidth;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getFieldMaxWidth(tab_name VARCHAR(40), fld_name VARCHAR(40), OUT value INT(11)) 
    BEGIN
        SET @t1:= CONCAT('SELECT MAX(LENGTH(',fld_name,')) FROM ',tab_name, ' INTO @value');
        PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
        EXECUTE stmt3;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
    END;

CREATE PROCEDURE modifyFieldMaxWidth(IN tab_name VARCHAR(40), IN fld_name VARCHAR(40))
    BEGIN
        SET @t1:=256;
        CALL getFieldMaxWidth(tab_name, fld_name, @t1);
        SET @t2:=CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',tab_name,' CHANGE ',fld_name,' ',fld_name,' VARCHAR(',@t1,')');
        PREPARE stmt4 FROM @t2;
        EXECUTE stmt4;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt4;
    END$$
```

What I keep getting back is this error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

Which states

> incorrectly use a reserved word

Can anyone help me here? Not sure what reserved word mySQL thinks I am using incorrectly?

Comment: It should be `Drop Procedure If exists`. Secondly, at the end of first stored procedure, you should have `End $$` not `End ;`. Remember that delimiter is `$$` at that moment

Comment: Thanks for your response but that doesn't answer the question, which was " Not sure what reserved word mySQL thinks I am using incorrectly?"